# Java method is returning 0 regardless of methods output

Tags: java

I have the following method in my YahtzeeHand class:

```
int faceValue(int n){

    int count = 0;

    for(Die die : dice){
        if(die.getCurrentValue() == n){
            count++;
        }
    }

    return n * count;
}
```

dice is an ArrayList of Die objects and .getCurrentValue gets the value of the die.

I am trying to determine how many Die in the the dice ArrayList have a value of n and multiply that number (count) by n.

```
System.out.printf("%s",faceValue(1));
```

The method keeps returning 0 regardless of whether there is a Die object with the value of 1 or not. Do you have any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong here and how I can get it to return "n * count"?

**EDIT: To clarify things here are my three classes:**

DieTester.java

```
package com.company;

public class DieTester {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        YahtzeeHand report = new YahtzeeHand();

        report.reportLine();

    }

}
```

YahtzeeHand.java

```
package com.company;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class YahtzeeHand {

    public int numDice, numSides, occurrences;
    private int sum = 0;

    private ArrayList<Die> dice = new ArrayList<>();

    YahtzeeHand(){
        numDice = 5;
        numSides = 6;
    }

    YahtzeeHand(int numDice){
        this.numDice = numDice;
    }

    YahtzeeHand(int numDice, int numSides){
        this.numDice = numDice;
        this.numSides = numSides;
    }

    void rollDice(){
        for (Die die : dice){
            die.roll();
        }
    }

    public String toString() {

        String result = "";
        for (Die die : dice) {
            result = result +  " " + die;
        }
        return result;
    }

    int countDice(){
        return numDice;
    }

    void setDice(Die firstDice, Die secondDice, Die thirdDice, Die fourthDice, Die fifthDice){

        dice.add(firstDice);
        dice.add(secondDice);
        dice.add(thirdDice);
        dice.add(fourthDice);
        dice.add(fifthDice);

    }

    int faceValue(int n){

        int count = 0;

        for(Die die : dice){
            if(die.getCurrentValue() == n){
                count++;
            }
        }

        return n * count;
    }

    int threeKindValue() {

        boolean threeKind = false;

        ArrayList<Integer> listOfValues = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Die die : dice) {
            listOfValues.add(die.getCurrentValue());
        }

        for (Integer num : listOfValues) {
            if (Collections.frequency(listOfValues, num)>2 ) threeKind = true;
        }

        if (threeKind){
            for(Integer num2 : listOfValues){
                sum += num2;
            }

            return sum;
        } else return 0;

    }

    int fourKindValue() {

        boolean fourKind = false;

        ArrayList<Integer> listOfValues = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Die die : dice) {
            listOfValues.add(die.getCurrentValue());
        }

        for (Integer num : listOfValues) {
            if (Collections.frequency(listOfValues, num)>3 ) fourKind = true;
        }

        if (fourKind){
            for(Integer num2 : listOfValues){
                sum += num2;
            }

            return sum;
        } else return 0;

    }

    int fullHouseValue(){

        boolean fullHouseThree = false;
        boolean fullHouseTwo = false;

        ArrayList<Integer> listOfValues = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Die die : dice) {
            listOfValues.add(die.getCurrentValue());
        }

        for (Integer num : listOfValues) {
            if (Collections.frequency(listOfValues, num) == 3) fullHouseThree = true;
        }

        for (Integer num : listOfValues) {
            if (Collections.frequency(listOfValues, num) == 2) fullHouseTwo = true;
        }

        if (fullHouseThree && fullHouseTwo) return 25;
        else return 0;
    }

    int largeStraightValue(){

        ArrayList<Integer> listOfValues = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Die die : dice) {
            listOfValues.add(die.getCurrentValue());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < listOfValues.size() - 1; i++) {
            if (listOfValues.get(i) != listOfValues.get(i + 1) - 1) {
                return 40;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    int yahtzeeValue(){
        boolean yahtzee = false;

        ArrayList<Integer> listOfValues = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Die die : dice) {
            listOfValues.add(die.getCurrentValue());
        }

        for (Integer num : listOfValues) {
            if (Collections.frequency(listOfValues, num) == 5 ) yahtzee = true;
        }

        if (yahtzee){  return 50; } else return 0;
    }

    int chanceValue(){

        ArrayList<Integer> listOfValues = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Die die : dice) {
            listOfValues.add(die.getCurrentValue());
        }

        for (Integer num : listOfValues) {
            sum += num;
        }

        return sum;
    }

    void reportLine (int lineNum){

        YahtzeeHand hand = new YahtzeeHand();

        Die die1 = new Die(hand.numSides);
        Die die2 = new Die(hand.numSides);
        Die die3 = new Die(hand.numSides);
        Die die4 = new Die(hand.numSides);
        Die die5 = new Die(hand.numSides);

        hand.setDice(die1, die2, die3, die4, die5);
        hand.rollDice();

        System.out.printf("%s.  %s    %s", lineNum, hand.toString(), faceValue(1));
    }
}
```

Die.java

```
import java.util.*;

public class Die {

    private int numSides, roll;

    private Random random = new Random();

    Die(int numSides) { this.numSides = numSides; }

    public Die() { this(6); }

    public int getCurrentValue() { return roll; }

    public String toString() { return roll +  " "; }

    int roll() {
        roll = random.nextInt(numSides) + 1;
        return roll;
    }

    public void cheat(int cheater) {
        if (cheater < 0 ) System.out.println("Can't be negative");
        else this.roll = cheater;
    }

    public void reallycheat(int reallyCheat) {
        this.roll = reallyCheat;
        System.out.println("Stop trying to cheat so much!");
    }
}
```

Comment: @Eran apologies. That is what I have and edited the post to correct it. With n * count, it is returning 0.

Comment: what content does 'dice' have?

Comment: @Stultuske I made an edit to that post. I actually have n * count in my method which returns 0, regardless of whether there is a die with the value n.

Comment: Either `n` or `count` is 0. Where do you create the `Die` objects?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong here, the problem must be in some part of the code you did not show.

Comment: Maybe you should dump your 'dice' list so that you can see what's in it, and maybe show us.  If 'dice' is a list of Die objects, and it has at least one Die object in it that returns 'n' when die.getCurrentValue() is called on it, then you should not be getting a return value of 0.  The code you're showing us is fine.  It must be the contents of the 'dice' list that explains why you get 0.

Comment: @DMellon this is perfect for debugging - why don't you start a debugger and go line by line to understand better the code you wrote and see what's actually happening? I am certain you will find what the problem is if you do that.

Comment: Yeah...debugger...that's the ticket.

Comment: @MC Emperor Made an edit to display all my code for clarity.

Comment: @Henry Made an edit to display all my code for clarity.

Comment: @Steve Made an edit to display all my code for clarity.

Comment: @hovanessyan thank you.. I will give that a shot.

Comment: If you can't run a debugger on your original block of code, you could print 'n' and then print the value returned by die.getCurrentValue() for each loop iteration. That should show you what's going wrong.

Comment: I guess this isn't doing what you think it is doing: Die die1 = new Die(hand.numSides);
        Die die2 = new Die(hand.numSides);
        Die die3 = new Die(hand.numSides);
        Die die4 = new Die(hand.numSides);
        Die die5 = new Die(hand.numSides);

Comment: @Stultuske I think it is creating a new die object with the numSides perimeter being set to the number five which is the value set to numSides in the YahtzeeHand constructor.

Comment: Sorry, but you need to learn how to run a debugger.

Comment: why do you create five identical objects? you can easily create one, and pass that to the setDice method. Seeing as they all have the same value, either all of them are checked, or none of them, which would explain the result of 0

Comment: That's what I had originally had but my assignment directions state this:

"void setDice() : Accept five parameters as the values for all five dice"

I would really like to take your suggestion as it would make everything simpler but my professor wants it to have five parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you have two `YahtzeeHand` instances.

The first is created in your `main`:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    YahtzeeHand report = new YahtzeeHand();
    report.reportLine();
}
```

However, in `reportLine`, you create a second instance:

```
void reportLine (int lineNum)
{
    YahtzeeHand hand = new YahtzeeHand(); // second instance created

    Die die1 = new Die(hand.numSides);
    Die die2 = new Die(hand.numSides);
    Die die3 = new Die(hand.numSides);
    Die die4 = new Die(hand.numSides);
    Die die5 = new Die(hand.numSides);

    hand.setDice(die1, die2, die3, die4, die5); // dice added to second instance
    hand.rollDice();

    System.out.printf("%s.  %s    %s", lineNum, hand.toString(), faceValue(1)); // faceValue(1) called for original instance
}
```

You call `setDice` for the second instance (`hand.setDice(die1, die2, die3, die4, die5)`), but call `faceValue(1)` for the original instance, which has no dice.

Just eliminate the second instance:

```
void reportLine (int lineNum)
{
    Die die1 = new Die(numSides);
    Die die2 = new Die(numSides);
    Die die3 = new Die(numSides);
    Die die4 = new Die(numSides);
    Die die5 = new Die(numSides);

    setDice(die1, die2, die3, die4, die5);
    rollDice();

    System.out.printf("%s.  %s    %s", lineNum, toString(), faceValue(1));
}
```

Comment: Fixed. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

`YahtzeeHand(int numDice)` will not set numSides, hence rolls will have an upper limit of 0.

One way to prevent this kind of out-of-date constructors is to call one single full constructor:

```
YahtzeeHand() {
    this(5, 6);
}

YahtzeeHand(int numDice) {
    this(numDice, 6);

}

YahtzeeHand(int numDice, int numSides) {
    this.numDice = numDice;
    this.numSides = numSides;
}
```

Comment: Changed those and it is still returning 0.

Comment: I was almost afraid of that; a second error then; as `new YahtzeeHand(5)` was used.

Comment: A look did show no problems IMHO. So you need to debug. BTW `System.out.printf("%d.  %s    %d%n", lineNum, hand.toString(), faceValue(1));` is better. Maybe first do a clean build.